# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For each program, how many people have a Programming Skill knowledge of less than 4? Report one row for each existing program.

```
df1['ProgSkills'<4].groupby(by=df1['Program']).count()
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Data frame:

[image: Data frame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1['ProgSkills'<4]
```

This literally compares the string `ProgSkills` to the number 4.

You meant to do

```
df1[df1['ProgSkills']<4]
```

Which will compare each value in the `ProgSkills` column to the number 4.